# What is an example of a compact non-uniformizable space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, uniform-spaces

Every compact Hausdorff space is uniformizable.  But I don’t think every compact space is uniformizable.  So my question is, what is an example of a compact non-uniformizable space?

Comment: As an aside: every compact Hausdorff space is even *uniquely* uniformisable: there is exactly one uniformity that will induce its topology. This also holds for the non-compact space $\omega_1$ in the order topology.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma What other examples are there of noncompact spaces which are uniquely uniformizable?  Is there a general result about under what conditions a space is uniquely uniformizable?

Comment: They are exactly the spaces that are so-called "almost compact": there is a unique compactification of $X$ (up to equivalence). Exercises 8.5.11 and 12 in Engelking "General Topology" (2nd ed.) have references and a bit more. It's not  a well-studied class.See also Gilman and Jerrison exercises 6J and 15R for more equivalent formulations.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I posted a question on this, if you want to elaborate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2953476/71829

Comment: I expanded the above comment for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the topology on every uniform space is completely regular, and hence regular.

Let $X$ be Sierpinski space, i.e. $X=\{0,1\}$ with the topology $\{\emptyset,X,\{0\}\}$. Then $X$ is trivially compact, but is not regular because $\{1\}$ is closed and doesn't contain $0$, but every open set containing $\{1\}$ also contains $0$. Thus, $X$ is not uniformizable.

Comment: Is there a less trivial example?

Comment: Yes, https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces?q=compact%20%2B%20~Regular

Comment: OK thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

A topology from a uniform space is $R_0$ (also called symmetric). This means that topologically distinct points can be separated by disjoint open sets, where points $x \neq y$ are topologically *indistinguishable* iff $\overline{\{x\}} = \overline{\{y\}}$ (or equivalently if for every open set $O$ we have $x \in O$ iff $y \in O$). So e.g. a $T_1$ space that is $R_0$ is also Hausdorff (because then the closures of singletons are singletons, so all points are distinguishable and must be "separatable"). The same holds for $T_0$ spaces (because $T_0$ can be seen as equivalent to "all distinct points of $X$ are topologically distinguishable"). This means that the following are standard examples of compact non-$R_0$ spaces: The cofinite topology on any infinite set, the excluded point topology on any set, as they are $T_0$ and not $T_2$.

That a topology from a uniformity is $R_0$ is a standard fact (and follows from the fact that every entourage $D$ contains a symmetric entourage $E$, i.e. one where $E = E^{-1}$).

Any indiscrete space is uniformisable (trivially) and is an example of a compact uniformisable space that is not Hausdorff. 
But if $X$ is uniformisable then $T_0$, $T_1$, $T_2$, $T_3$ and Tychonoff are all equivalent properties (if you have one, you have them all), so in a way, indiscrete is the best you can do as far as non-Hausdorff examples go (finite sums of them, too, if you like)